# define constant in php

Tags: php, class-constants

how do I define a constant inside a function

eg.

```
class {

     public test;

     function tester{

      const test = "abc";

     }

  }
```

Comment: Just pointing out that you should not be defining a constant inside a function, anyway. That should probably be a property of the object, not a constant of the class, since constants should never have the opportunity to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing fine but you need to put the `const` at the class level not inside the function eg:

```
class {
 const TEST = "abc"; 
 public $test2;

 function tester{
  // code here
 }
}
```

**[More info here.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)**

Also, you were missing `$` in public variable `test`

Answer (score 5):

I think you want a [Class Constant](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

```
class SomeClass {

  const test = "abc";

  function tester() {
    return; 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

By definition, you shouldn't be assigning a value to a constant after its definiton. In the class context you use the `const` keyword and `self::` to access it through the class internally.

```
class TestClass
{
    const test = "abc";

    function tester()
    {
        return self::test;
    }
}

$testClass = new TestClass();
//abcabc
echo $testClass->tester();
echo TestClass::test;
```

You can see that you can also access the constant as a static class property using `::`

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php